# Highlight an item in jQuery UI Multiselect Next

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, highlight, multi-select

I have jQuery UI Multiselect Next http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next I want to highlight an item using a colour.

For example, I have:

```
<select id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="countries[]">
    <option value="Afghanistan" selected="selected">Afganistan</option>
    <option value="Albania" selected="selected">Albania</option>
    <option value="Austria" selected="selected">Austria</option>
    <option value="Germany" selected="selected">Germany</option>
</select>
```

Is possible highlight Germany in red?

Comment: Can you a bit clear abt this...in that example everything is there right

Comment: I want to change the color ONLY of specific items, for example: Albania and Austria. Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/aEMzb

Comment: Then try adding dynamic id to the selected item..and then through css u can apply those styles right

Answer (score 1):

I am using this to highlight the 4th row:

```
.ui-multiselect ul.selected >  li:nth-child(3)
{
    background:none;
    background-color:green;
}
```

If you want to do it for multiple replace `li` with `li:nth-child(2n+1)` for all odd etc…

Hope this helps.